# Creating pie chart using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use the piechart to count the number of transactions under each flat type but has encountered this error message ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'blk'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d3 = np.genfromtxt("flattransactions.csv",
    delimiter=',',skip_header=1,
    dtype=[('month','U8'),('resale_price','i8'), ('flat_type','U8'),('blk','i8'),],missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])

labels = ['flat_type']
values = ['blk','resale_price']

colors = ['#FA8F0A','#F0DA32','slateblue','#61F527','#18DE9D','#3594FF','orange']
explode = (0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.pie(values, labels=labels,colors=colors,autopct='%1.1f%%')
 
plt.show()
```

The output was a x and y axis graph with no data instead of a pie chart shape.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d3 = np.genfromtxt("flattransactions.csv",
                   delimiter=',', skip_header=1,
                   dtype=[('month', 'U8'), ('resale_price', 'i8'), ('flat_type', 'U8'), ('blk', 'U8')],
                   missing_values=['na', '-'], filling_values=[0])

flat_types, counts = np.unique(d3['flat_type'], return_counts=True)

colors = ['#FA8F0A', '#F0DA32', 'slateblue', '#61F527', '#18DE9D', '#3594FF', 'orange']
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.pie(counts, labels=flat_types, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=140)
plt.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.title('Transactions per Flat Type')
plt.show()
```